# Content obscuring Google-served ads in Flutter with App Open Ads

Tags: flutter, admob

I am receiving a warning in my Admob account for "Content obscuring Google-served ads". The screenshot attachment for this issue that they found is what you can see below:

[image]

I am not sure which one is in obscuration. Is it the App Open Ads obscuring the banner ad beneath it? (There is a banner ad in my homepage) If so, how do I hide if the App Open Ads is visible?

This is the guide I followed for the implementation of App Open Ads in Flutter: https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/app-open